# Convert column's data to enumerated dictionary key-value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, enumeration

Is there a better way (in the sense of minimal code) that can do the followings: convert a column to enumerated numerical values so it should go somewhat this way:

1. get a **set** of items in a columns
2. make a **enumrated dictionary** with key value
3. revert the key with value
4. use the key-value result instead of the data in a new column.

So here's what I do today and wonder if anyone can show a classic way to do that so I can avoid writing the function *get_color_val*:

```
import pandas as pd  
cars = pd.DataFrame({"car_name": ["BMW","BMW","ACCURA","ACCURA","ACCURA","BMW","BMW","BMW"],"color":["RED","RED","RED","RED","GREEN","BLACK","BLUE","BLUE"]})

color_dict = dict(enumerate(set(cars["color"])))
color_dict = dict((y,x) for x,y in color_dict.iteritems())

def get_color_val(row):
    my_key = row["color"]
    my_value = color_dict.get(my_key)
    return my_value

cars["color_val"] = cars.apply(get_color_val, axis=1)
cars = cars.drop("color",1)
print cars
```

> Result

```
Before------------
car_name  color
0      BMW    RED
1      BMW    RED
2   ACCURA    RED
3   ACCURA    RED
4   ACCURA  GREEN
5      BMW  BLACK
6      BMW   BLUE
7      BMW   BLUE


After------------
car_name  color_val
0      BMW          3
1      BMW          3
2   ACCURA          3
3   ACCURA          3
4   ACCURA          2
5      BMW          1
6      BMW          0
7      BMW          0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [pd.factorize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) in this case:

```
In [8]: cars['color_val'] = pd.factorize(cars.color)[0]

In [9]: cars
Out[9]:
  car_name  color  color_val
0      BMW    RED          0
1      BMW    RED          0
2   ACCURA    RED          0
3   ACCURA    RED          0
4   ACCURA  GREEN          1
5      BMW  BLACK          2
6      BMW   BLUE          3
7      BMW   BLUE          3
```

Comment: @adhg, yeah, yet another reason to love Pandas... ;)